# FaceNet for dummies

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

The FaceNet algorithm (described in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03832.pdf) article) uses a convolutional neural network to represent an image in an 128 dimensional Euclidean space.

While reading the article I didn't understand:

1. How does the loss function impact on the convolutional network (in normal networks, in order to minimize the loss the weights are slightly changed -
   backpropagation - so, what happens in this case?)

[image]

1. how are the triplets chosen?

   2.1 . how do I know a negative image is hard

   2.2 . why am I using the loss function to determine the negative image

   2.3 . *when* do I check my images for hardness with respect to the anchor - I believe that is *before* I send a triplet to be processed by the network, right.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some of the answer that may clarify your doubts:

1. Even here the weights are adjusted to minimise the Loss, its just the loss term is little complicated. The loss has two parts(separated by + in the equation), `first part` is the image of a person compared to a different image of the same person. The `second part` is the image of the person compared to a image of a different person. We want the `first part` loss to be less than the `second part` loss and the loss equation in essence captures that. So here you basically want to adjust the weights such that `same person error` is less and `different person error` is more.
2. The Loss term involves three images: The image in question(anchor): `x_a`, its positive pair: `x_p` and its negative pair: `x_n`. An `hardest positive` of `x_a` is the positive image that has the biggest error compared to the rest of the positive images. The `hardest negative` of `x_a` is the closest image of a different person. So you want to bring the furthest positives to be close to each other and push the closest negatives further away. This is captured in the loss equation.
3. `Facenet` calculates its anchor during training (online). In each `minibatch`(which is a set of 40 images) they select the `hardest negative` to the anchor and instead of choosing the `hardest positive` image, they choose all anchor-positive pairs within the batch.

If you are looking to implement `face recognition`, you should better consider this [paper](http://ydwen.github.io/papers/WenECCV16.pdf), that implements `centre loss`, which is much easier to train and shown to perform better.

Comment: Can you please detail number 3? The thing that confuses me is that the hardest negative is calculated by the network - (using function f which produces an embedding) - but at the same time is necessary as input.

Comment: f(x) is outputs and Loss is calculated based on the outputs of model. Where it is fed as input?

Comment: From what I understood the CNN takes 3 images at a time (from a set of 10000 or more) as input: the anchor, the positive and the negative. Because you don't want to analyze all the combinations of 3 images of the set, you want to choose hard negative images (that are close enough to the anchor, but not as close as the positive). If I am wrong, what is the input?

Comment: In the paper, the input is a batch of 40 images and for each image as an anchor, you select one `hardest negative` in the batch based on the outputs of 40 images in the batch. Thats why its called inline training.

Comment: can you please explain how does FaceNet compute the accuracy? From what I understood, I check the distance between the anchor and the positive, and between the anchor and the negative, and determine which one is "closer". If the positive embedding is closer to the anchor, the result is correct. Am I right?

Comment: Once its trained, you obtain the embeddings `f(x)` for each of the face in the training set and form a dictionary. For testing a new face get the embeddings and find L2 loss to all the dictionary items and choose the minimum. If the labels are same then its a match.

Comment: Can you please explain how online training works? For now, I understood that, based on the outputs of the network, I choose the hard negative for each image in the batch. Then I use these pairs (anchor, positive, hard negative) to calculate the error and update the weights? What does a batch contain? Images of different people or many images of the same person along with a few negatives (images of other people). Thank you so much!

Comment: @vijaym I would also be very grateful if you could wrote some more about online training.